# Make mathematica "forget" numbers beyond the precision goal

Tags: machine-precision

I need *Mathematica* to remember only things upto two decimal places.

I'm currently using the unwieldy `Floor[x*100]/100` which works but is there a better way to make it use two decimal places (throughout the notebook is okay).

I tried `N[x,{2,2}]` but although it displays the requisite two decimal places, I know that the kernel still remembers. For instance, if I try it for `N[1.234,{2,2}]-1.23` is not `0`. It is in fact `0.004`. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Examine `FullForm@N[1.234, {2, 2}]` and you'll see it's not doing what you think it is doing.  Try instead ```SetAccuracy[1.234, 2] - 1.23``2```.  One problem using this approach is that *Mathematica* tracks relative precision, not a fixed number number of decimal places.  Do you want fixed-point arithmetic or is just about output formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `Round[]` for this:

```
Round[1.234, 1.*^-2] - 1.23
   0.
```

This can be used with `$PrePrint` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

To make your function work "throughout the workbook" you can use:

```
$PrePrint = N @ Floor[#*100]/100 &;
```

Now

```
 {1.23999, Pi}
```

> {1.23, 3.14}

Restore `$PrePrint` to the default:

```
$PrePrint =.
```